# force long text inside \item[{\texttt{}] to wrap

Tags: line-breaking, input, description

I have a LaTeX document that is automatically generated and then inserted as part of my own larger document with `\input`. This other document has a description environment for examples, one item for each. The problem is that some of them are very long and run out of the paper margins. Here's an example,

```
\begin{description}

\item[{\texttt{bp\_genbank\_ref\_extractor --transcripts=accession '"homo sapiens"[organism] AND H2B'}}] \mbox{}

Search Entrez gene with the query \texttt{'"homo sapiens"[organism] AND H2B'}, and
save their transcripts sequences. Note that default value of \textbf{--limit} may only extract
some of the hits.


\item[{\texttt{bp\_genbank\_ref\_extractor --transcripts=accession --proteins=accession --format=fasta '"homo sapiens"[organism] AND H2B' '"homo sapiens"[organism] AND MCPH1'}}] \mbox{}
```

Is there a way to force them to wrap around without changing the file? Something I can do before calling `\input`? The text there will run for several pages and is a section of the appendixes (I'm using the `memoir` class).

This document is generated automatically from the POD documentation of a perl script using `pod2latex`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `enumitem` package has an option to `description`: `style=unboxed` and thus the contents of `\item[...]` is then wrapped. One might also get away by redefining `\descriptionlabel`, though I don't think the broken line will be indented (I tend to like having them stand out, so when I use there very long titles I have the text start on the next line after the title.

Comment: that worked fine. The package does not accept the option with `\usepackage`. Instead, I had to use `\setlist[description]{style=unboxed}`. I set it right before the call to `\input` to avoid changing the rest of the document. Still, it may affect whatever comes after. Do you know how to make this options apply only there?

Comment: I have found how to do it. It's in the manual. Basically, just set the style back to standard after. The following sequence does what I wanted `\setlist[description]{style=unboxed}`, `\input{documentation}`, `\setlist[description]{style=standard}`.

Answer (score 5):

The following works for [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) as well as the standard document classes (`article`, `book` and `report`). It avoids using the `\item` label (passed as an optional argument) of description, and rather unskips the space inserted after it was usually set. The reasoning here is that, by default, the `\item` label is set in a box, which doesn't break across the line boundary.

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
  \item[{\texttt{bp\_genbank\_ref\_extractor --transcripts=accession '"homo sapiens"[organism] AND H2B'}}] \par
    Search Entrez gene with the query \texttt{'"homo sapiens"[organism] AND H2B'}, and
    save their transcripts sequences. Note that default value of \textbf{--limit} may only extract
    some of the hits.

  \item \hspace*{-\labelsep}%
    \textbf{\texttt{bp\_genbank\_ref\_extractor --transcripts=accession '"homo sapiens"[organism] AND H2B'}} \par
    Search Entrez gene with the query \texttt{'"homo sapiens"[organism] AND H2B'}, and
    save their transcripts sequences. Note that default value of \textbf{--limit} may only extract
    some of the hits.

  \item {\hspace*{-\labelsep}\raggedright
    \textbf{\texttt{bp\_genbank\_ref\_extractor --transcripts=accession '"homo sapiens"\hspace{0pt}[organism] AND H2B'}} \par}
    Search Entrez gene with the query \texttt{'"homo sapiens"[organism] AND H2B'}, and
    save their transcripts sequences. Note that default value of \textbf{--limit} may only extract
    some of the hits.
  \end{description}
\end{document}
```

I've used `\raggedright` and possibly some `\hspace{0pt}` here/there to allow breaking it a proper location; it seems like you're dealing with some constructs that require some help in that regard.

Note that lists are usually document class dependent. So more work/investigation is required for document classes other than the ones listed above.

Comment: thanks for the tip but I cannot change the input file where the actual description environment is. I can only add code on my own LaTeX document before, or after the call to `\input`.

Answer (score 4):

If you have the possibility to change the input file, I would suggest not to use a list but a sectioning command. This will also prevent a page break between the "title" and the text of the entry. Here an example with the `\minisec` command of the KOMA-classes:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

\setkomafont{minisec}{\ttfamily}
\minisec{bp\_genbank\_ref\_extractor --transcripts=accession '"homo sapiens"[organism] AND H2B'}
Search Entrez gene with the query \texttt{'"homo sapiens"[organism] AND H2B'}, and
save their transcripts sequences. Note that default value of \textbf{--limit} may only extract
some of the hits.


\minisec{bp\_genbank\_ref\_extractor --transcripts=accession --proteins=accession --format=fasta '"homo sapiens"[organism] AND H2B' '"homo sapiens"[organism] AND MCPH1'}
Search Entrez gene with the query \texttt{'"homo sapiens"[organism] AND H2B'}, and
save their transcripts sequences. Note that default value of \textbf{--limit} may only extract
some of the hits.


\end{document}
```