# How can I make the item label in the description environment wrap?

Tags: lists, description, wrap

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item[This is a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long header line:] blah blah
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

In the above, the item label ("This is a very ... long header line:") does not wrap. How can I make it wrap?

Comment: You can find an answer in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55412/wrong-line-break-in-description-environment-after-a-long-label, though the question isn't exactly a duplicate.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96267/force-long-text-inside-item-texttt-to-wrap, this is the same question I guess.