# How can I make the label text in description lists wrap in the label area over multiple lines if needed?

Tags: tables, lists, enumitem, description

I use the `enumitem` package to customise description lists. Here a MWE printing some fictitious personal details:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[description]{leftmargin=5em, labelindent=0em, labelwidth=4.5em,
                      align=right}

\begin{document} 
\begin{description}
\item[Address]
3 Whole St, Wondertown WXY 2722
\item[Email]
aldo.thoughful@etheral.con
\item[Phone]
123 55 66 78
\item[Secondary Phone]
123 78 66 55
\item[Nationality]
Wonderland, Republic of Home and Mother Country
\item[Security Clearance]
National Clearance 13.2 with a very, very, very,
very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very,
very, very, very, very long explanation
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

The output looks basically like this:

```
    Address   3 Whole St, Wondertown WXY 2722
      Email   aldo.thoughful@etheral.con
      Phone   123 55 66 78
Secondary Phone 123 78 66 55
Nationality   Wonderland, Republic of Home and Mother Country
Security Clearance National Clearance 13.2 with a very, very, very,
              very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very,
              very, very, very long explanation
```

Some labels don't fit - of course in the `\setlist[description]` I could increase the necessary dimensions, but I'd rather not move the position of  the label/text-separation. Instead I'd like the labels to wrap *in the label area* over multiple lines like this:

```
    Address   3 Whole St, Wondertown WXY 2722
      Email   aldo.thoughful@etheral.con
      Phone   123 55 66 78
  Secondary   123 78 66 55
      Phone
Nationality   Wonderland, Republic of Home and Mother Country
   Security   National Clearance 13.2 with a very, very, very,
  Clearance   very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very,
              very, very, very long explanation
```

Ideally the line breaks in the label would happen automatically on spaces. Is there a way to achieve this with `enumitem` or otherwise?

*Note 1*: I saw the stackexchange question ["Force long text inside item to wrap"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96267/force-long-text-inside-item-texttt-to-wrap), but I can't make it apply to my situation.

*Note 2*: I don't want to change the environment I use. `tabular`-like environments could certainly be a good fit, but the whole input texts are already set in description lists, so I want to keep it this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a new style similar to multiline, but

- you will have to setup a better labelwidth and
- you will have to insert empty lines with `\\~` if the description text is too short.

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{enumitem,calc}

  \makeatletter 
  \def\enit@align@parright{%
    \def\enit@align##1{%
      \nobreak
      \strut\smash{\parbox[t]\labelwidth{\raggedleft##1}}}}

  \def\enit@style@multilineright{%
    \enit@align@parright
    \enit@calcset\labelindent\z@{0pt}%
    \enit@calcset\leftmargin\thr@@!}
  \makeatother    

  \setlist[description]{labelwidth=\widthof{\bfseries Nationality},
                        style=multilineright}

  \begin{document}
  \noindent xxxxxxx
  \begin{description}
  \item[Address]
  3 Whole St, Wondertown WXY 2722
  \item[Email]
  aldo.thoughful@etheral.con
  \item[Phone]
  123 55 66 78
  \item[Secondary Phone]
  123 78 66 55\\~
  \item[Nationality]
  Wonderland, Republic of Home and Mother Country
  \item[Security Clearance]
  National Clearance 13.2 with a very, very, very,
  very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very,
  very, very, very, very long explanation
  \end{description}

  \end{document}
  ```

[image]